# java or c library to read svn authz file

Tags: java, svn

recently,I want to parse svn authz file like that

```
[aliases]
joe = /C=XZ/ST=Dessert/L=Snake City/O=Snake Oil, Ltd./OU=Research Institute/CN=Joe Average

[groups]
harry_and_sally = harry,sally
harry_sally_and_joe = harry,sally,&joe

[/foo/bar]
harry = rw
&joe = r
* =
```

is there a java or c library to parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if [suafe in google code](http://code.google.com/p/suafe/source/browse/trunk/suafe-core/src/main/java/org/suafe/core/impl/AuthzFileParser.java?r=312) is what you are looking for

Comment: I check it ,suafe is not thread safe,if you want to modify a field ,you should parse all the element in the auth file to memory,then write it to output file